# Can I see local git bare repository graphically like github?

Tags: git, windows-server-2008

I have a bare repository in a server, it works ok but I need to show the project and usefully information about it as GitHub does.

Is it possible? If answer is true, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using windows

Comment: Sorry about that… Windows is always an exception there, as Git was conceived for *nixes mainly. Seems `instaweb` is only available on those.

Comment: @slhck so, what else can I do? is there something like **instaweb** for windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of front-ends for windows.

One is [GitStack](http://gitstack.com/). Another is [WebGitNet](https://github.com/otac0n/WebGitNet/). [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com/) is one based on Java.